# How to split a date string and get the resulting strings in different variables?

Tags: javascript

I have variable 
`var dataValue = '10/2019'`
and I want to get value 2019 and 10 in different variables. So I have `var dataA = 10, and var dataB = 2019`

How to solve the problem about that?

Comment: This is about simple Javascript where you can use .split function and has got nothing to do with React/React Native

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have reasonable variable naming and defaults for the variables, I'd suggest doing it like this:

```
const date = '10/2019';
const [ month = 'defaultMonth', year = 'defaultYear' ] = date.split('/');
```

This will ensure that you get no undefined (which leads to RSoD in RN).

Answer (score 0):

Use split function from js like below:

```js
var dataValue = '10/2019' 
var spliter = dataValue.split('/')

var data1 = spliter[0]
var data2 = spliter[1]

console.log("result: ", data1, data2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
var actual_value = '10/2019' 
var data = actual_value.split('/')

var data1 = data[0] // returns "10"
var data2 = data[1] // returns "2019"
```